# How to join strings together

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, join

I have a string array called hexsub, each "instance" of the array holds 2 characters. I made a new array called finalhex, i wanted that each "instance" of the new array held 2 of the previous, so: hexsub(0)=06, hexsub(1)=AF, then finalhex(0)=06AF. How can i do this?

Comment: You have the answer in the title of your question: [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join function will join all the elements of the array regardless of how many there are within reason of course.

```
finalhex(0) = Join(hexsub,"")
```

or to split them up in pairs, something like this might work:

```
For I = 0 to hexsub.Count-1 Step 2
  finalhex(I/2) = hexsub(I).Trim + hexsub(I+1).Trim
Next
```

Now each element of finalhex will contain 2 concatenated elements of hexsub

Comment: Ok, but i get a space between each element of the array at the resulting string, how can i make this spaceless?

Comment: Add .Trim to each of the hexsub elements.  I edited my answer.

Comment: You must have added a space between the quotes or used the default delimiter.  The empty quotes in my answer also work.

Answer (score 0):

'assuming an even number of array elements

```
Dim NumberOfCombinedElements as Integer = hexsub.count / 2

Dim FinalHex(NumberOfCombinedElements ) as string

for I as integer = 0 to NumberOfCombinedElements - 1

    finalhex(I) = hexsub(I*2) & hexsub(I*2 + 1)

next
```